# создает список через циклический ввод

Tags: python

Напишите программу, которая создает список через циклический ввод по input(), длина списка должна быть произвольной, т.е. определить условие конца ввода и принимать неограниченное количество элементов до наступления этого условия. На выходе получите из этого списка кортеж. определите длину кортежа L и выведите его средние элементы с индексами i>L /2.

новичок не пониаю от слова совсем

помогите(

Comment: Не может быть чтобы вы ничего не понимали. Вы разместили вопрос тут, значит что-то знаете. Дополните вопрос всем что вы знаете по задаче.

Comment: я примерно что-то понимаю, но из того что пишу ничего не работает, или работает не правильно

Comment: Вставляйте ваши попытки в вопрос  с объяснением чего хотели, что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Псевдокод на псевдопитоне, ибо учебное задание, переводите на питон сами (и учитесь!):

```
создать пустой список

бесконечный цикл:
    ввести очередное число
    если это число равно некоему числу, означающему конец цикла:
        прервать цикл
    добавить введённое число в список

преобразовать список в кортеж
определить длину кортежа
определить индекс середины кортежа
```

А вот про средние элементы я тоже не совсем понял, но у вас и без того тут есть над чем поработать.